# sparql query on wikidata

Tags: sparql, wikidata

i am very new to sparql and i am trying to run 3 queries on wikidata:

1. Persons who are not painters and who are students of painters.
2. Persons who are not painters and who are academic offspring or children of painters (note: an academic offspring of a person `P` is somebody who is/was a student of `P`, or a student of a student of `P`, or .... ).
3. People who are academic offspring of themselves.

i got stuck on the first one, i tried:

```
SELECT DISTINCT ?human ?humanLabel WHERE {
  ?human wdt:P31 wd:Q5.
  SERVICE wikibase:label { bd:serviceParam wikibase:language "[AUTO_LANGUAGE],en". }
  ?human wikibase:statements ?statementcount.
  ?human wdt:P106 ?profession.
  FILTER(?profession != wd:Q1028181)
  FILTER(?statementcount > 50 )
  ?human wdt:P1066 ?teacher.
  ?teacher wdt:P106 ?tprofession.
  FILTER(?tprofession = wd:Q1028181)
  OPTIONAL {  }

}LIMIT 50
```

but i think in this line: `FILTER(?profession != wd:Q1028181)`, is not checking all the professions against painter but just the first one, so i get painters that have multiple occupations in the output because is checking just the first occupation against painter, but i want all those occupations checked against painter.

Comment: that is correct. Absence of information is done via `FILTER NOT EXISTS {?human wdt:P106 wd:Q1028181}`

Comment: How does this relate to <https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58580901/sparql-new-query-on-wikidata>? And how do these relate to <https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58581648/sparql-query-with-wikidata>?